# ASP.NET Core : package.json is missing

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, webpack, asp.net-core-1.0

As per the following [link](http://www.talkingdotnet.com/where-is-package-json-in-aspnet-core/): when creating ASP.NET Core  App, You have just show all files in solution to find the package.json, but in my case i am not able to find it. I need to add angular2 and  WebPack dependencies.

So what is the problem?

Comment: (I don't have enough reputation to add notes to other answers yet.) Vasanth: I think they are talking about the package.json used by npm. The project.json file, on the other hand, is (or... was) the ASP.NET project file.

Comment: Yes, Exactly that was for npm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add `package.json` in Visual Studio 2015 like this-

Right click on Project > Add > New Item. In new Item popup window, you can select **npm configuration file** like below-

[image: package.json]

Comment: But, why its not added by default?

Comment: I m not sure... but probably because npm consider as external tools

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a front end expert but I do recall during one of the ASP.NET community standups Mads Kristensen talking about a bundling and minification changes that I think may have replaced gulp etc as the default. Maybe the default template no longer pulls in npm because of that?

I can see bower only in the new ASP.NET core template.

But as Sanket says, you can add in what you want.

Links to the bundler/minifier stuff below:

https://youtu.be/p6NUkeTVsGE?list=PL0M0zPgJ3HSftTAAHttA3JQU4vOjXFquF - Mads talking on bundling.

https://github.com/madskristensen/BundlerMinifier/wiki

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9ec27da7-e24b-4d56-8064-fd7e88ac1c40

Answer (score 0):

You should use `npm init -y` to initialise package.json.